# Change values in 3d numpy array based on condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d array, and for each block, I want find the columns which have two zeros, and change the one with lower row index to -1, but I cannot get the index in the 3d array correct.

```
            # col1 col2
a=np.array([[[-2, -1],   # row1
             [-1,  0],   # row2    block1
             [ 0,  0]],  # row3   
            [[-1, -1],   # row1
             [-1,  0],   # row2    block2
             [ 0,  0]]]) # row3
mask=(a[:,1,:]==0)&(a[:,2,:]==0)
a[:,1,mask]=-1

# Desired output:
a=np.array([[[-2, -1],
             [-1,  -1],
             [ 0,  0]],
            [[-1, -1],
             [-1,  -1],
             [ 0,  0]]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "block", "row" and "column"? For a 3D-array these are not well defined terms.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it correctly, u can get it by using the code below.

```
a = np.array([[[-2, -1],
               [-1,  0],
               [ 0,  0]],
              [[-1, -1],
               [-1,  0],
               [ 0,  0]]])

filter = np.where(np.sum(a[:, [1, 2], :] == 0, axis=1) >= 2)

for i, j in zip(*filter):
    a[i, np.argmin(a[i, :, j] != -1), j] = -1

print(a)
```

Comment: I would recommend a different name for your mask, as `filter()` is a standard Python function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have some initial data:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
   [[[-2, -1], 
     [-1,  0],     
     [ 0,  0]],    
    [[-1, -1], 
     [-1,  0],     
     [ 0,  0]]]) 

new_value = -1
```

As far as not each column can be the one with 2 (or more) zeros, we will address the cells of interest like:

```
data[xs, ys, zs] = new_value
```

where `xs`, `ys`, `zs` are sequences of the same length with corresponding coordinates of zero cells. For example, if

```
zero_cells = [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)]
```

then

```
xs = [0, 3]
ys = [1, 4]
zs = [2, 5]
```

But first, let's move the axis of interest to the last position:

```
arr = data.transpose([0, 2, 1])
```

The new array is a *view* to the initial data, so any changes will be reflected there as well. Whereas the new axis arrangement will give us some advantages in the form of automatically sorted output.

Let's select the cells which satisfy the required conditions:

```
is_zero = (arr == 0)
col_has_two_zeros = (is_zero.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True) == 2)
coord = np.argwhere(is_zero & col_has_two_zeros)
```

Here `coord` is a two-dimensional array of sorted zero cells coordinates from columns with exactly 2 zeros, where each row is one such cell. Each pair of rows contains cells of the same "column", and the first in this pair will be the cell with the smaller coordinate along the "column" (here by "column" I mean the last axis).

So all we have to do now is:

```
xs, ys, zs = coord[::2].T
arr[xs, ys, zs] = new_value
```

In case if we are interested in columns with not exactly but at least 2 zeros, we need to find rows in `coord` where the first two coordinates are different from the data in a previous row:

```
col_has_many_zeros = (is_zero.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True) >= 2)
coord = np.argwhere(is_zero & col_has_many_zeros)

is_first = np.diff(coord[:, :2], axis=0, prepend=-1).sum(axis=-1).astype(bool)
xs, ys, zs = coord[is_first].T
arr[xs, ys, zs] = new_value
```

---

Code for experiments:

```
import numpy as np


# Case 1: columns with exactly 2 zeros

new_value = 42

data = np.array(
   [[[ 0, -2],      
     [-1,  0],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 0, -2]],    
    [[-1, -1], 
     [-1,  0],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 1,  3]]]) 

expected = np.array(
   [[[ 0, -2],      
     [-1, 42],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 0, -2]],    
    [[-1, -1], 
     [-1, 42],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 1,  3]]]) 


arr = data.transpose([0, 2, 1]) 

is_zero = (arr == 0)
col_has_two_zeros = (is_zero.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True) == 2)
coord = np.argwhere(is_zero & col_has_two_zeros)

xs, ys, zs = coord[::2].T
arr[xs, ys, zs] = new_value

assert np.array_equal(data, expected)


# Case 2: columns with at least 2 zeros

new_value = 77

data = np.array(
   [[[ 0, -2],      
     [-1,  0],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 0, -2]],    
    [[-1, -1], 
     [-1,  0],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 1,  3]]]) 

expected = np.array(
   [[[77, -2],      
     [-1, 77],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 0, -2]],    
    [[-1, -1], 
     [-1, 77],     
     [ 0,  0],
     [ 1,  3]]]) 


arr = data.transpose([0, 2, 1]) 

is_zero = (arr == 0)
col_has_many_zeros = (is_zero.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True) >= 2)
coord = np.argwhere(is_zero & col_has_many_zeros)

is_first = np.diff(coord[:, :2], axis=0, prepend=-1).sum(axis=-1).astype(bool)
xs, ys, zs = coord[is_first].T
arr[xs, ys, zs] = new_value

assert np.array_equal(data, expected)
```